# XCode Bots API configuration edit fails

Tags: xcode, api, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I want to change via the XCode Bots API the scheme name of a bot. A request like curl -XPATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'x-xcsclientversion: 8' https://localhost:20343/api/bots/botid123 -d '{"name": "myawesomebot2"}' to change the bot name works. But if I try to change the configuration object with a request body like '{"configuration": {"schemeName": "scheme2"}}' it fails.

How can the scheme name be modified?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?
So far, in my testing, I've been able to set a -d JSON payload of

'{"name": "cool_bot", "configuration": {"scheduleType": 2}}'

and that's it. Modifications to something like sourceControlBlueprint (so I can point the bot to a new branch on the repo) either seem to be ignored or return a "Class of object ((null)) is not a subclass of XCSBotConfiguration"

Similar problems for you, I guess?
Did you ever arrive at a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this solved and want to note the pieces necessary to make this work and how I found it.

First, as you already noticed, is the need for `-H "x-xcsclientversion: #"` (note, 6 worked for me, as discovered through a check of Apple's Javascript that receives the PATCH request)

Second, after watching Xcode Server update a bot through Charles, it was seen that the URL needs the following parameter added, `?overwriteBlueprint=true`

Third, it seems that the JSON data, at the topmost level as `name:`, also requires `requiresUpgrade=false` and `type=1` ([I found the tool jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to be invaluable)

Fourth, changes to the `sourceBlueprint` requires `configuration.sourceControlBlueprint.DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey` to receive a new UUID. Easily generated in bash by `uuidgen` command.

Fifth, a mostly-full bot description must be sent. I grabbed the bot's JSON definition through Apple's API, then modified it using `jq` (see above), deleting out unnecessary key/value pairs so as to match Xcode Server's own API calls. The necessary key/value pairs appear to be:

- name
- type
- requiresUpgrade
- configuration (modify as necessary, but a full configuration must be sent)
- group (leave as-is, but send it back through)

Sixth, backslash-escape all forward-slashes in the JSON payload. I've done this in bash with `ESCAPED_JSON=${BOT_CONFIG_JSON//\//\\\/}` and I send `-d "$ESCAPED_JSON"` in the curl command.

As such, the full curl command I'm using becomes:

```
curl -k --request PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-xcsclientversion: 6" -d "$ESCAPED_JSON" https://<username>:<password>@<your_server_address>:20343/api/bots/<your_bot_id>?overwriteBlueprint=true
```

And a full JSON definition (remember, it must have forward slashes escaped before sending) looks like this

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->
  "requiresUpgrade": false,
  "configuration": {
    "triggers": [
      {
        "phase": 1,
        "scriptBody": "<REDACTED>",
        "type": 1,
        "name": "Update github Pending",
        "conditions": {
          "status": 2,
          "onSuccess": true,
          "onAnalyzerWarnings": true,
          "onBuildErrors": true,
          "onWarnings": true,
          "onFailingTests": true
        }
      },
      {
        "phase": 2,
        "scriptBody": "<REDACTED>",
        "type": 1,
        "name": "Upload to Beta",
        "conditions": {
          "status": 2,
          "onSuccess": true,
          "onAnalyzerWarnings": true,
          "onBuildErrors": false,
          "onWarnings": true,
          "onFailingTests": false
        }
      },
      {
        "phase": 2,
        "scriptBody": "<REDACTED>",
        "type": 1,
        "name": "Update github status",
        "conditions": {
          "status": 2,
          "onSuccess": true,
          "onAnalyzerWarnings": true,
          "onBuildErrors": false,
          "onWarnings": true,
          "onFailingTests": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "performsUpgradeIntegration": true,
    "disableAppThinning": true,
    "deviceSpecification": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "platform": {
            "_id": "3c884e2499df662057e8c64580003419",
            "displayName": "iOS",
            "_rev": "8-51c114fcfc83ea5f36df66f119b34ec8",
            "simulatorIdentifier": "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator",
            "identifier": "com.apple.platform.iphoneos",
            "buildNumber": "14C89",
            "version": "10.2"
          },
          "filterType": 3,
          "architectureType": 0
        }
      ],
      "deviceIdentifiers": [
        "6d928bd891b83b4b8592aedb42001a97",
        "6d928bd891b83b4b8592aedb4200776c",
        "fa737f03db7b6c04d4c7f9507100700f"
      ]
    },
    "periodicScheduleInterval": 0,
    "schemeName": "<REDACTED>",
    "codeCoveragePreference": 2,
    "performsTestAction": true,
    "scheduleType": 3,
    "performsArchiveAction": true,
    "builtFromClean": 2,
    "buildConfiguration": "Release",
    "performsAnalyzeAction": true,
    "sourceControlBlueprint": {
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintLocationsKey": {
        "A2739AD29C3BCDF8619D0305ACFDD0C22AEBDDB1": {
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintLocationTypeKey": "DVTSourceControlLockedRevisionLocation",
          "DVTSourceControlLocationRevisionKey": "9d38dc7507f0f6ac17072d721893f0021c5282ed"
        },
        "51DBFAD1848AC646B864BBBEDC625B8BAB305A76": {
          "DVTSourceControlBranchIdentifierKey": "<THE BRANCH TO WATCH>",
          "DVTSourceControlBranchOptionsKey": 4,
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintLocationTypeKey": "DVTSourceControlBranch"
        }
      },
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintPrimaryRemoteRepositoryKey": "51DBFAD1848AC646B864BBBEDC625B8BAB305A76",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyRepositoryLocationsKey": {},
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryAuthenticationStrategiesKey": {
        "A2739AD29C3BCDF8619D0305ACFDD0C22AEBDDB1": {
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryAuthenticationTypeKey": "DVTSourceControlAuthenticationStrategy"
        },
        "51DBFAD1848AC646B864BBBEDC625B8BAB305A76": {
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryAuthenticationTypeKey": "DVTSourceControlAuthenticationStrategy"
        }
      },
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey": {
        "A2739AD29C3BCDF8619D0305ACFDD0C22AEBDDB1": 0,
        "51DBFAD1848AC646B864BBBEDC625B8BAB305A76": 0
      },
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey": "<GENERATE A NEW UUID FOR THIS!!!>",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey": {
        "A2739AD29C3BCDF8619D0305ACFDD0C22AEBDDB1": "<REDACTED PATH 1>",
        "51DBFAD1848AC646B864BBBEDC625B8BAB305A76": "<REDACTED PATH 2>"
      },
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintNameKey": "Cool Blueprint",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintVersion": 204,
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRelativePathToProjectKey": "<REDACTED>.xcworkspace",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey": [
        {
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey": "git@github.com:<REDACTED REPO 1>",
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey": "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git",
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey": "A2739AD29C3BCDF8619D0305ACFDD0C22AEBDDB1"
        },
        {
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey": "git@github.com:<REDACTED REPO 2>",
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey": "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git",
          "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey": "51DBFAD1848AC646B864BBBEDC625B8BAB305A76"
        }
      ]
    },
    "exportsProductFromArchive": true,
    "weeklyScheduleDay": 0,
    "minutesAfterHourToIntegrate": 0,
    "testingDestinationType": 0,
    "hourOfIntegration": 0,
    "testingDeviceIDs": []
  },
  "group": {
    "name": "41A62776-A72E-44C0-BFF0-D91F699BBA6A"
  },
  "type": 1,
  "name": "My Cool Integration Bot"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: in similar way xcode does update the bots. it sends a mostly complete config json object. to send only the updated property does not seem to work. even if the documentation says that it should work.

Comment: Exactly correct. Ultimately, my success came from mimicking what Xcode does as precisely as possible, including sending data that doesn't seem to be necessary (why resend every integration script again?!)

Comment: Quick comment for those discovering and up-voting this, even 5 years later. I'd like to note that I have been using the above method unaltered this entire time with no problems. Solution still appears to be compatible (i.e. I have it in daily production use driving two critical build servers) with Xcode 13.4.1.