# Xcode bot does not see repository branches

Tags: xcode-bots

After updating the XCode to version 11.4 (11E146), I stopped seeing repository branches in the bot settings. But I see these repository branches in Source Controll Navigator. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

[image: bot settings]

Answer (score 5):

This issue was resolved in Xcode 12.

---

OLD answer & workaround for Xcode 11.4 - 11.x:

Unfortunately it's a known issue in the Xcode 11.4 release. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes

Find this Stack Overflow answer to change the branch manually via the Xcode Server API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42573925/1372065

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: @Bora14 Glad to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I updated Xcode to version 12.1 (12A7403) and the problem disappeared. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is fixed in XCode12, In case you still need to use XcodeServer on Xcode 11.4 - 11.5 then follow the below steps

In the final step, add a pre-integration script and add the below git commands

```
git pull
git checkout `your-branch-under-test`
git branch
```

Comment: Well thats no good if you have commit based build triggers